# Javascript how to detect mousedown only when a mouse is clicked, not taps

Tags: javascript, android, web, web-applications

I'm making a web app. On Chrome for Android when when I tap, document.onmousedown happens. How do I respond to only clicks and not taps? I want to respond as soon as the mouse button is pressed, not wait until it is released.

I want a solution that does not use jquery or anything.

If they plug in a mouse to their device (even an android) I want the clicks to get detected.

Comment: do you want to use that in reactjs?

Comment: I don't want to use react

Comment: so you are developing in Android Studio, Am I right? there is no mouse down in Android, do you mean click?

Comment: no I'm just developing in javascript and the target user is using the Chrome app

Comment: you might looking for touchstart? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart